# Select table id from ASP.net table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my structure in ASP.net:

```
<table runat="server">
  <tr id='1'> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='2'> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to get the id of the clicked table row. this is my Javascript code:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('tableID'));
```

Unfortunately, the alert result is `undefined`.

When I look into the source code of the page, there is an `id` for each table row.  How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try `$(this).parent('tr').attr('id')`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));//use id instead of tableID
```

Comment: I still get the same message undefined. I run this code in a iframe

Comment: When i run this code
alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));

Comment: Now i tried this but stil doesn't work:
alert($('#content').contents().find('#test').closest('tr').attr('id')); the id of my iframe=content. My table name=test. In test i try to get the id of te tr's

Answer (score 0):

Replace tableID with the ClientID of your asp.net table.

```
$('#tableID tr').click(function() { alert(this.id); });
```